# Travis yml to run Selenium Java Gradle Docker build

Tags: java, selenium, docker, gradle, travis-ci

I'm looking for an example `.travis.yml` file that would execute a Gradle build inside a Docker container that would run my Selenium tests. So far I've seen various blog posts and answers, but they are either in a language that I'm not looking for like JavaScript, or they use Maven instead of Gradle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got a working example after piecing it together from various blogs:
`.travis.yml`

```
sudo: required
dist: trusty
language: java
jdk:
  - oraclejdk8

script:
  -  gradle clean test
before_install:
  - docker run -d -p 4444:4444 -p 5900:5900 -v /dev/shm:/dev/shm -e VNC_NO_PASSWORD=1 selenium/standalone-chrome-debug:latest
before_cache:
  - rm -f  $HOME/.gradle/caches/modules-2/modules-2.lock
  - rm -fr $HOME/.gradle/caches/*/plugin-resolution/

cache:
  directories:
    - $HOME/.gradle/caches/
    - $HOME/.gradle/wrapper/
```